# AS3 , Facebook API - Can't retrieve image from event object after image loads

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api

I am getting a mysterious result when trying to load profile images from a logged in Facebook user's friends list into an as3 canvas app.  In pretty much every (**non-facebook**) application I've made where loading an image is required I use the following:

```
private function loadPic():void
{
    var url:String = Facebook.getImageUrl(_friendslistObjectArray[_loadCount].id);
    _picLoader = new Loader();
    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
    _picLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onPicLoaded);

    _picLoader.load(req);
}

private function onPicLoaded(evt:Event):void
{
    _picLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onPicLoaded);

    // grab image from loader event to use it       
    var image = evt.target.content;

    trace("this trace won't even show up and the program silently fails unless the line above this is removed");

    _loadCount++;
    loadPic();
}
```

I can't retrieve the image from the event object, and I am given no error at all.  It all just fails silently.  If I remove the line **var image = evt.target.content**, the process runs through the whole array.

I can't think of any reason this would occur.  Furthermore, if I look in firebug's net activity, I see I see the images get loaded as long as I do not have the line I just mentioned included.  I just can't seem to get the image data from the event object to add it to stage or a container movieclip.

This should be very easy.  I'm racking my brain here trying to figure out what I missed or what is wrong.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

This line:

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/crossdomain.xml");
```

Placed right before **_picLoader.load(req);** fixes the problem.

It was a crossdomain error, but for some unknown reason the error did not report until I threw **var image = evt.target.content;** into a try/catch and read the error message.

Props to this post for the answer:
[Load profile image from Facebook with Actionscript 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965214/load-profile-image-from-facebook-with-actionscript-3)

Answer (score 0):

the `evt.target` should be a `LoaderInfo` object, try the code here:

```
var image = (evt.targe as LoaderInfo).loader.content;
```